# DataFrame - remove rows that contains stop words or numbers in the 'word' column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nltk

I have dataframe with two columns(words, and count how those words), ordered by count:

```
    Word            Count
0   the             5337
1   boy             895
2   who             5891
3   lived           3150
4   mr              3443
... ... ...
6049    manner      3256
6050    holiday     2702
6051    347         276
6052    spreading   4937
6053    348         277
```

**What I want, is to remove the stop words, and the numbers (like '347' and '348'). e.g. in the example, remove rows 0, 2, 6051, 6053 ('the', 'who', '347', '348').**

This is how I created the DataFrame:

```
count_words_dict = {'the': 5337, 'boy': 895, 'who': 5891, 'lived': 3150, 'mr': 3443, 'and': 462, 'mrs': 3444, 'dursley': 1797, 'of': 3618, 'number': 3599, 'four': 2240, 'privet': 4007, 'drive': 1749, 'were': 5842, 'proud': 4034, 'to': 5431, 'say': 4397, 'that': 5336, 'they': 5346}
df = pd.DataFrame(list(count_words_dict.items()), columns = ['Word','Count'])
df.sort_values(by=['Count'], ascending=False)
df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

I also got the stop words:

```
!pip install nltk
import nltk
nltk.download("stopwords")

from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stops =  set(stopwords.words('english'))
```

But how can I remove those stop words (and preferably the numbers) from the DataFrame?

---

I saw in [this blog post](https://medium.com/bigpanda-engineering/exploratory-data-analysis-for-text-data-29cf7dd54eb8) that they managed to remove the stop words from trump's tweets dataset, but I didn't manage to make his code to work on my dataset. This is his code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stops =  set(stopwords.words('english')+['com'])
co = CountVectorizer(stop_words=stops)
counts = co.fit_transform(data.Tweet_Text)
pd.DataFrame(counts.sum(axis=0),columns=co.get_feature_names()).T.sort_values(0,ascending=False).head(50)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pandas.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`pandas.Series.str.isnumeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html) to first remove words matching from the `stopwords` list and then exclude numeric values from `Word` column:

```
count_words_dict = {'the': 5337, 'boy': 895, 'who': 5891, 'lived': 3150, 'mr': 3443, 'and': 462, 'mrs': 3444, 'dursley': 1797, 
                    'of': 3618, 'number': 3599, 'four': 2240, 'privet': 4007, 'drive': 1749, 'were': 5842, 'proud': 4034, 
                    'to': 5431, 'say': 4397, 'that': 5336, 'they': 5346, '345':200, '555':1000}

df = pd.DataFrame(list(count_words_dict.items()), columns = ['Word','Count'])
df.sort_values(by=['Count'], ascending=False)
df.reset_index(drop=True)

from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stops =  list(stopwords.words('english'))
df = df[~df['Word'].isin(stops)]
df = df[~df['Word'].str.isnumeric()]
```